# How can I have a PyTorch Conv1d work over a vector?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I understand `Conv1d` strides in one dimension. But my input is of shape `[64, 20, 161]`, where 64 is the batches, 20 is the sequence length and 161 is the dimension of my vector.

I'm not sure how to set up my `Conv1d` to stride over the vector.

I'm trying:

```
self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(batch_size, 20, 161, stride=1)
```

but getting:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 20 64 161, expected input[64, 20, 161] to have 64 channels, but got 20 channels instead
```

Comment: `torch.nn` modules always expect the first dimension of input to be the batch size, you don't specify that in the constructor. So the 64 does not have to be modelled by you. From the documentation, the signature is `torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, ...)`. If you want 20 channels in and 20 channels out, replace `batch_size` by 20 and you should be fine.

Comment: I guess I want 161 channels in and out, right? Since that's the dimension of each timestep? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, that's your task. I can just tell you that your `in_channels` is 20 and that you don't have to state the batch size anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d):

```
torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros')
```

in_channels is the number of channels in your input, number of channels usually an computer vision term, in your case this number is 20.
out_channels size of your output, it depends on how much output you want.

For 1D convolution, you can think of number of channels as "number of input vectors" and "number of output feature vectors". And size (not number) of output feature vectors are decided from other parameters like kernel_size, strike, padding, dilation.

An example usage:

```
t = torch.randn((64, 20, 161))
conv = torch.nn.Conv1d(20, 100)
conv(t)
```

**Note:** You never specify batch size in torch.nn modules, first dimension is always assumed to be batch size.